# NSZombie created with -Os and Automatic Reference Counting in iOS 5 development

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nszombie

I spent the day working on a strange error in my iOS 5 iPad application, and I was wondering if anyone had some information.

Here's the general setup: There's a UIViewController subclass StoryViewChildController that has two member variables: `_currentModel` and `_comingModel`. There is a method in StoryViewChildController that calls `[[INEWSStoryModel alloc] init]` and returns the resulting object that was created. During `viewDidLoad`, I have the following code block. Note that this isn't verbatim copied from the code - it's more complicated - but I'm trying to summarize:

```
_currentModel = [self createModel];
_comingModel = [self createModel];
```

Then, at some point, I need to be able to swap _currentModel and _comingModel, along with other objects. Here is the swap method, verbatim from my code:

```
- (void)swapComingPageAndCurrentPage {

  [_swapLock lock];
  //Swap story views
  IPCStoryView *swapPage = _currentPage;
  _currentPage = _comingPage;
  _comingPage = swapPage;

  //Swap models
  INEWSStoryModel *swapModel = _currentModel;
  _currentModel = _comingModel;
  _comingModel = swapModel;

  //Swap players
  PlayerController *swapPlayer = _currentPlayerController;
  _currentPlayerController = _comingPlayerController;
  _comingPlayerController = swapPlayer;

  // clear out the content of the old view
  [_comingPage resetStoryView];
  [_comingPlayerController resetPlayer];
  _comingPlayerController.view.alpha = 0.0; 

  _currentPageURI = _lastRequestedStory;
  [_swapLock unlock];
}
```

The problem is: when I'm run my project in Release configuration (which uses -Os for compiler optimization) I crash during the swap of the model objects. The crash comes from attempting to access a Zombie object. I used Instruments to track down the retain/release path of my objects, and coming into this method, _currentModel has a reference count of 1, as expected. However, the line `INEWSStoryModel *swapModel = _currentModel;` does NOT cause a retain to be called on _currentModel, so the next call `_currentModel = _comingModel;`, causes the reference count to drop to 0. Then, when `swapModel` falls out of scope, another release call is attempted, and the program crashes.

It almost seems to me that the compiler optimization is optimizing away retain calls that it should not. Has anyone else had this type of problem? Could I be doing something else wrong? If necessary I can post more code from the class.

Other interesting notes: If I set the swapModel variable as __autoreleasing, the code works. Also, if I add the following code block at the end of the swap method, the code works:

```
_comingPage.cueView.frame = [_comingPage adjustCueViewFrame:_comingPage.cueView.frame
                              ForVideoShowing: NO
                                inOrientation:_currentOrientation];
```

All that method does is adjust a UIView frame. The fact that I can add unrelated code to the end of the method and have it not create a zombie leads me to think the compiler is optimizing incorrectly. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This certainly seems odd. I can't seem to reproduce the problem with a small test case. Any chance you can cut stuff back as far as you can go whilst you're still seeing the problem?

Comment: That’s **really** odd. What does the assembly say? In what way does it change when you include the frame update?